# Wordpress subpage dosen't switch name

Tags: wordpress

I have website with blog, I would love to change my post name to witch I choose not with default one.

Now it looks like this:
https://kasacja-aut.pl/blog/?p=221

I want to switch the name post to the same as in the head but when I do this Wordpress can't find the page.

I'm changing the option in Settings -> Direct Links

I can't change the simple one to this one below:
https://kasacja-aut.pl/blog/%postname%/

Comment: I think you mean `Settings > Permalinks` If that's where you are changing it, your `.htaccess` file may not be getting written to correctly.  https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ Check that link for the default `.htaccess` settings. Check here for how to fix: https://www.000webhost.com/blog/fix-not-working-permalinks-in-wordpress/

Comment: Yes I meant Permalinks. I did everything from both links that you have send. I tried to delete and upload posts when I change format form "simple one" to "/%postname%/" It's impossible. 

It shows: 
There is an autosave of this post that is more recent than the version below.

View the autosave Updating failed. 

The response is not a valid JSON response.

It redirects to the page with %postname% but it's 404.